# What's the smart way to add two durations together? (JS/PHP/SQL)

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I'm talking about two durations (e.g., "2 hours, 4 minutes" + "7 hours, 2 minutes"); *not* two timestamps. I googled this for a while and everything I could find was talking about calculating the differences between dates.

I'm using SQL, PHP and JavaScript; my database has a list of events with their durations, and I want to be able to sum up the total duration from a `SELECT` statement. The obvious solution is to substring the time, saying

```
total secs = first two chars*60*60 + second two chars*60 + last two chars
```

then multiply total secs by `60*60` to get a duration in decimal hours, round it down and keep the remainder for `HH:mm`... but that seems messy. Is there a cleaner, more proper solution I should be using?

Comment: "but that seems messy" --- it doesn't. "To clarify, the information is stored in a MySQL 'time' field, in the format HH:MM:SS." --- why don't you use mysql for that then? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec

Comment: adding `2hours 31minutes + 3hours 6 seconds` is messy. adding two time fields in mysql is as simple as `field1 + field2`

Comment: As others have stated, ideally store that values in the time field. Using php you can read in the record and use /(\d{1,2})/ to strip out the numbers from the fields. You need to process the number of returned items for example: 3 days 2hours 31minutes + 3hours 6 seconds will return 5 values and 2hours 31minutes + 3hours 6 seconds returns 4 values.

Answer (score 1):

you should change field "time" to "int"

Answer (score 1):

Times can be added by converting to a common unit (say minutes in this case), add the mintues, then convert back to hours and minutes.

If you have a string like "2 hours, 4 minutes" you can convert it to minutes using something like:

```
function stringToMinutes (s) {  
  var a = s.match(/\d+/g);
  return a[0]*60 + +a[1];
}
```

Convert back to hours and minutes like:

```
function minutesToString(m) {
  function addS(n) {return n!= 1? 's' : '';}
  var hr = m / 60 |0;
  var min = m % 60;
  return hr + ' hour' + addS(hr) + ', ' + min + ' minute' + addS(min);
}
```